# Repair system_auth keyspace in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0

According to official documents, system keyspace uses Local replication strategy so there is no need to repair it, my question is about system_auth keyspace, should I manually run repair on this keyspace?

When I use full repair without specifying any keyspace, I expect to see system_auth being repaired in the log file, but I can't see any indication that system_auth is getting repaired.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only some system keyspaces are using the local replication strategy.  The `system_auth` uses `SimpleStrategy` with replication factor 1 by default (see [docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#enabling-password-authentication)).  If you have a cluster of several nodes, then it's recommended to set replication strategy to `NetworkTopologyStrategy` (even if you have one DC - it will help in the future) and increase replication factor to 3 in each DC.  And then you need to run repairs on it to have it in consistent state.

P.S. Also, create a new superuser (see [step 5 in docs](https://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/security.html#enabling-password-authentication)), because default `cassandra` uses `QUORUM` when reading login data, and it could be a problem if you lose half of the machines.